# Best way for a rails db seed file to delete existing data in certain table before seeding, to prevent duplicate data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, seeding

I have several tables in a rails app.
One table contains seeded data that I now want to update, without touching other tables.
However, simply using `rake db:seed` will duplicate my data, if I'm not mistaken.

Can I include a command like
 `ModelName.delete_all`
at the beginning of a seed file?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my best practices, I will make use of `first_or_initialize` method to make sure we create update existing data without destroying them. For example, you have created several users in your seed data like this

```
3.times do |i|
   User.create(email: "abc@example.com", name: "Test #{i}")
end
```

Then you should do like this

```
3.times do |i|
   user = User.where(email: "abc@example.com").first_or_initialize
   user.name = "New Test #{i}"
   user.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, but if ModelName has any associations at all you're going to screw up your foreign key IDs.  Sounds kind of risky.

Now that said... I have some code in a seed file to load a small set of very specific data into a model.  I have a hash containing all the fields that I want and then I loop through that and either find-and-update or create the rows.

```
providers = {
  foo: {name: 'Foo', ...},
  bar: {name: 'Bar', ...}
}

providers.each do |(code, attrs)|
  p = Provider.find_by(code: code) || Provider.new(code: code)
  p.update!(attrs)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I include a command like ModelName.delete_all at the beginning of a seed file?

Off course you can, seed.rb is just a series of ruby (and rails) commands, so you can do anything you want with it.

In some of my projects I delete the entire database from seed.rb with the following snipet:

```
tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - ['schema_migrations']

tables.each do |table|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DELETE FROM `#{table}`"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "ALTER TABLE `#{table}` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1"
end
```

With this snipet, no need to worry about association or linked ids. The only garbage that would remain is linked files (through carrierware or paper_trail for example) in your public folder. For that case you would need to manually clean those folders.

Another advantage of that snipet is that you don't have to update it while adding new tables in your project, because it takes care of deleting all table, except `schema_migrations` which is used by rails to keep track of the migration that was included/are pending